# Extract word between the sentence which are not the same as the last word

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to capture input from a textbox and extract word that are not the same as the last word anyone with an idea how it's done in c#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = inputTextBox.Text;
    string[] parts = s.Split(' ');
    string lastword = parts[parts.Length - 1];

    if (s != lastword)
    {                        
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < s.Length - 1; i++){ if (s[i] != lastword) { // do something } }`

Comment: `parts.Where(x => x != lastword).ToArray()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `System.Linq` solution.  This returns all  words that are not the last word.

```
string s = "hello this is my list hello";
string[] parts = s.Split(' ');

var words = parts.Where(w => w != parts.Last());

// write to console
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", words));

// output
// this,is,my,list
```

Another option is to use a loop:

```
string s = inputTextBox.Text;
string[] parts = s.Split(' ');
string lastword = parts[parts.Length - 1];

for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length - 1; i++)
{
    if (parts[i] != lastword)
    {
        // do something                  
    }
}
```